# what is the different between http request and web service

Tags: web-services

I have googled about "web service" and I also read it in [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service):

> A Web service is a method of communications between two electronic
>   devices over the World Wide Web

However I can not make it clear about what is the web service mean.

How about the common http request which return xml or json rather than a html content? For example:

http://www.server.com/ws/getitem?id=xxxx

This is a interface used to get item detail by id, while return data of json or xml format.

Now if we implement it by so said web service manner, what will be done?

Answer (score 7):

A normal web page returns HTML, PDF, or image data that's intended to be displayed to the user in a browser.

A web service returns data that's intended to be used by another program, rather than displayed directly to the user; another common term for this is *API*, i.e. Application Programming Interface. Rather than returning HTML, it returns data that's structured to be easy for computers to extract the values. Common formats are [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) and [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). The web service might also use a structured format for requests, such as [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or [WSDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WSDL), but some (like your example) just use URL query parameters.

Both web services and normal web pages use HTTP as the data transfer protocol. The difference is in how they're used by clients.

Comment: Just addition, usually web services uses some kind of standard format to make requests/responses, for example [wsdl](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl)

Comment: I know the web service is used for communications, but in my example, the normal web request return json(or xml) data instead of html, and then the client(may be a browser,mobile device and etc),so is this a kind of web service. I doubt it.:(

Comment: If it returns JSON or XML, it's a web service, not a web page.

Comment: But I do not use anything about so said of SOAP,WSDL or RCP and etc, is this really a kind of service?

Comment: Web service is a very general term. It just means any use of HTTP to retrieve data or request an action, but not display a web page.

Comment: Read the last sentence of my first paragraph. It _might_ use a structured format, but it doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

I think if your link retuns a full html page, full of references to images, flash, sounds, zips, but your client is not a browser and simply ignores all these content and parse only what it wants from this html, it's scraping AND some sort of web service :-) although not very efficient one :-)

But if you make the same request from a browser, you're not parsing anything or doing anything useful in a programatic way, then I think it's not a web service.

If you're doing an ajax request in order to retrieve a piece of XML to append to your browser DOM, you're not parsing data to process, instead you just want to refresh a webpage, so I think it's not a web service.

If you're doing another ajax request to retrieve a JSON object to be interpreted by a javascript client-side code in a browser to show a little alert, you're not parsing the data to process, so I think it's not a web service either.

If you're making a http request to retrieve a PDF that you will parse with itext in order to do some data crunch, then maybe you're using a web service.

If you're making a http request to retrieve a plain text CSV file to automatically input into some database, I think it's a web service too.

So I really think the difference between a web service and something that is not a web service is if the other side of the interaction is a machine or a human being.

And that's why "typical" web services are made to make the robot job easier :-)

update: if it's someone in a suit selling for a high price, it's certainly a web service ;-)

ps: if I serve the same content with ftp instead of http, even ftp being used in a browser, is it still a web service or ftp is not web enough? :-)